# type org.apache.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException Storm

Tags: java, apache-storm

Every Time i tried to run i get this exception
Getting Topology submission exception. (topology name='hellow') #error 
     :cause nil
     :via
     [{:type org.apache.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException on line => cluster.submitTopology("hellow", config, builder.createTopology());

Below is my code for storm Topology.

```
This is my Bolt.java

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.storm.hellow;

import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Tuple;

/**
 *
 * @author zerebral
 */
public class Bolt extends BaseRichBolt {

    private OutputCollector collector;


    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer ofd) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


    public void prepare(Map map, TopologyContext tc, OutputCollector oc) {
        this.collector = collector;
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
       System.out.println(tuple);
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}



This is my Spout.java

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.storm.hellow;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Values;


/**
 *
 * @author zerebral
 */
public class Spout extends BaseRichSpout {

private SpoutOutputCollector collector;
    private static int collector_int = 0;


    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer ofd) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


    public void open(Map map, TopologyContext tc, SpoutOutputCollector soc) {
        this.collector = collector;
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }



    public void nextTuple() {
       this.collector.emit(new Values(new Integer(collector_int ++ )));
        Thread.yield();
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }



}   

This is my Topoloy.java

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.storm.hellow;

import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import org.apache.storm.utils.Utils;

/**
 *
 * @author zerebral
 */
public class Topology  {

    public static void main(String args[])  throws Exception
    {

        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("spout",new Spout(),1);
        builder.setBolt("numbers",new Bolt(),1).shuffleGrouping("spout");

        Config config = new Config();
        config.setDebug(true);

        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("hellow", config, builder.createTopology());

        Utils.sleep(100000);
        cluster.killTopology("hellow");
        cluster.shutdown();

    }

}
```